# What is the "list-symbol key" for on the logitech 915k keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

[image]

Between `fn` and right `ctrl` there is a list-symbol-like key, what is it for? And what is it called?

Answer (score 1):

Most PC keyboards have a [Menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) at this position. Pressing <kbd>≣</kbd> usually opens the context menu, similar to right-clicking with the mouse (but without needing a mouse, obviously), and similar to hitting Shift+F10.

(There also exist Windows apps which repurpose it as a "Compose" key, such as PuTTY.)